# Reverse Proxy FTP traffic

Tags: ftp, reverse-proxy

I was wondering if anyone knew of a reverse proxy server to reverse proxy ftp traffic.  I would like to run many servers on ip address, but then pass the traffic to an internal server with its own ip address.  Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Okay, I have a dedicated Linux machine providing firewall and routing to my whole network. I have several public ip addresses and I am doing a 1 to 1 port NAT for public servers behind the firewall. However, now I need to put several applications in their own virtual servers, but I am trying to avoid having to add a public ip address for each virtual machine. There are several web servers that provide a reverse proxy for web traffic. However, I am trying to figure out how to provide file editing capabilities as well. I am open to webdav or ftp, but most users prefer ftp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to  solve this problem. I like this setup:

```
                      +-------------+  
                      |  Gateway    |
                      |  NAT/Router |
                      |  216...     | 
                      +--+---+------+
                         |   |  
         +-- FTP ports --+   |       
         |                   |               
         |               Web ports
         |                   | 
    +----+--------+     +----+---------+    
    |  VM2 - FTP  |     |  VM1 - web   |    
    |  192...2    |     |  192...1     |      
    |  mounts     |     |  mounts      |    
    |   /www      |     |   /www       |    
    +-------------+     +--+--------+--+              
                           |        |                       
                     dom1 app proxy |                          
                           |        |
                           |  dom2 app proxy
                           |        |
                           |        |
                 +---------+---+ +--+----------+
                 |  VM3 - dom1 | |  VM4 - dom2 |
                 |  192...3    | |  192...4    |                 
                 |  mounts     | |  mounts     |
                 |  /www/dom1  | |  /www/dom2  |
                 +-------------+ +-------------+
```

The idea is that the gateway uses NAT and port-forwards the web 
and ftp requests to their respective VM's. The Web and FTP VM's use virtualhosts 
to manage the specific subfolders of /www based on requested domain. Then the 
web server proxies the dynamic content requests back the per-domain application
VM's which only have access to their own sub-directory. There is also no reason 
you can't have the web server serving WebDAV as well.

Answer (score 2):

We currently use JFTPGW - http://www.mcknight.de/jftpgw/

It has worked very well for us so far.

Here's the relevant section from my jftpgw config:

```
<global>
forward *@192.168.0.xx
reverselookups  yes
syslogfacility  daemon
commandtimeout 300
transparent-proxy   off
forwardlookups  yes
dnslookups  no
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I did not see where that will function as a reverse proxy.  It was interesting though.

Comment: I've updated my answer with my config. Have your DNS record and firewall direct FTP traffic to your reverse proxy. Then have the forward command in the config point to your internal FTP server.

Answer (score 0):

Why is a reverse proxy necessary?  Have you considered using a Destination NAT? (DNAT)

**Edit 1**

If you run Linux, depending on your infrastructure, you should be able to configure NATs on your server.  Your Linux server would have to be routing the traffic on the Internet routable IP to an internal network for this to be a functional solution.

If this is not helpful, you will need to provide additional details regarding your infrastructure for a more specific recommendation.

[Linux NAT HOWTO](http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/NAT-HOWTO.html)

**Edit 2**

[Network Address Translation](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&ct=res&cd=1&ved=0CBAQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FNetwork_address_translation&rct=j&q=network+address+translation&ei=YoyeS6zaIoGC8gbKpey7Cg&usg=AFQjCNE3M-Gg7yuoxBh5CKp2LjD13qOywA) will do what you describe.  Either by specifying different ports or configuring virtual hosts in your FTP daemon, which most modern daemons support.

Comment: I am using Linux, but I am not familiar with DNAT.  Will have to check into that, but can that mimic virtual hosting?  I want to point say ten domain names to the same ip address, but NAT them to separate internal ip addresses.  Thanks!

Comment: Okay,  I have a dedicated Linux machine providing firewall and routing to my whole network.  I have several public ip addresses and I am doing a 1 to 1 port NAT for public servers behind the firewall.  However, now I need to put several applications in their own virtual servers, but I am trying to avoid having to add a public ip address for each virtual machine.  There are several web servers that provide a reverse proxy for web traffic.  However, I am trying to figure out how to provide file editing capabilities as well.  I am open to webdav or ftp, but most users prefer ftp.