# Redirect all my inbound traffic of to another IP

Tags: networking, ip

I have two public IP's, xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx any yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy, I want to give xxx IP to client but IP yyy should be accessed. Is there a way I can do that?

Actually my FTP server is on IP yyy (suppose in UK), but I dont want to give this IP to client, instead I want to give him IP xxx(suppose of USA) to access my FTP.

Comment: Changing an IP address is called NAT (Network Address Translation). There are multiple variations of NAT, and it is not restricted to public/private translations. In fact, NAT has no idea what is a public address or a private address. The only difference between public and private addresses is that the ISP have agreed not to route the arbitrarily chosen private addresses on the public Internet.

Comment: Agreed...Can I NAT if I dont have both IP's on same PC's

Comment: When you NAT, you do not any of the IP addresses on the NAT device. NAT simply replaces one or more addresses in a packet before forwarding it on. There is, of course a lot more to it than that since you will need to maintain a NAT table, and the IP, TCP, UDP, ICMP, etc. checksums will need to be recalculated.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/122636/reverse-proxy-ftp-traffic

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it looks like the two Public IP addresses do not belong to the same ISP (one is in UK and other is in USA). To allow Public access from one to the other is to establish Internal connectivity between the two locations (Like a VPN Tunnel or Private Link), and then route Inbound traffic over the link.